# ajax source code - good open source project?

Tags: ajax

Whenever I want to study a new language, the best way IMO is to see how expert writes code in that language, that is always effecient.

I am looking for that :)

Comment: The title is pretty self-explanatory. Although "Ajax source code" is a bit off the mark, seeing as it's a technology, not a language. @Bin, do you want to use jQuery?

Comment: The idea of studying "expert code" is good, but not for starting off in a completely new world. For that you first need to understand the basic concepts and to read some simple examples. Good frameworks are usually everything else than simple examples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[First you should understand that what is AJAX](http://webdesign.about.com/od/ajax/a/aa101705.htm)

> Ajax is a way of developing Web
>   applications that combines:
>
> - XHTML and CSS standards based presentation
> - Interaction with the page through the DOM
> - Data interchange with XML and XSLT
> - Asynchronous data retrieval with XMLHttpRequest
> - JavaScript to tie it all together

[Simple Ajax Example](http://www.degraeve.com/reference/simple-ajax-example.php)

Answer (score 4):

AJAX isn't really a language in and of itself, it's used in tandem with other languages to create dynamic web applications. There isn't really a catch-all open source AJAX project that I'm aware of, although there may be some tailored to specific languages. Perhaps if you update the tags to elaborate on the language I can offer some suggestions.

Some resources you may be interested in:

http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/
http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp
http://code.google.com/edu/ajax/tutorials/ajax-tutorial.html